# hex string to signed int conversion in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I convert a hex strign to its 32 bit signed int equivalent in ruby?
for example

```
a = "fb6d8cf1" #hex string
[a].pack('H*').unpack('l') #from the documentation it unpacks to its 32 bit signed int
```

It converts to

```
-242455045
```

But the actual answer is

```
-76706575
```

Could you point me to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could flip the bytes yourself to get around the endian and sign issues:

```
>> ['fb6d8cf1'.scan(/[0-9a-f]{2}/i).reverse.join].pack('H*').unpack('l')
=> [-76706575]
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you had an endian problem. This gives the desired result:

```
[a].pack("H*").unpack("l>")
# => [-76706575]
["038a67f90"].pack("H*").unpack("l>")
#=> [59402233]
```

Comment: which version of ruby are you on? because even after using l> i still get -242455045

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

Comment: exactly the documentation also says the l> works only from 1.9.3. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade ruby on the production server and I have to find a workaround for this

Comment: Your original question didn't specify a Ruby version, so I went with what I had.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
class String
  def to_si(base, lenght = 32)
    mid = 2**(length-1)
    max_unsigned = 2**length
    n = self.to_i base
    (n>=mid) ? n - max_unsigned : n
  end
end

"fb6d8cf1".to_si 16, 32
```

Comment: THe code works for negative numbers. Thanks. But it fails for positive numbers for eg "038a67f90" is rendered as 950435728 but the actual value is 59402233