# How to convert in to signed int (4byte) using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to convert the follow 4 byte integer to signed integer, like:

input 65535 value  -1
input 65534 value  -2
input 65533 value  -3
and so on...

I tried the follow:

```
 puts (65533).to_s(16) #=> fffd
 puts (65533).to_s(16).unpack('s') #=> doesn't work properly... return 26214
```

Can someone help me with code above?
Best Regards

Comment: this looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963702/hex-string-to-signed-int-conversion-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-pack) it as as an unsigned integer and then [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-unpack) it as a signed integer:

```
[65535, 65534, 65533].pack('S*').unpack('s*')
#=> [-1, -2, -3]
```

`S` / `s` denote 16-bit integers, you can also use `L` / `l` for 32-bit or `Q` / `q` for 64-bit.